# can't connect to samba share files on ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, samba

First of all, i wanna quickly say, that i have no experience with linux or their cmds so it is okay to tell me stuff like i am stupid. cause i am.

So, i have a problem with my linux project i am currently working on.

At the moment, i have a pc with ubuntu linux server 20.04, a pc with ubuntu desktop and a windows 10, and i need to sambashare from the server to the windows and ubuntu machines, so each user has their designated folders with the right restrictions so only the right people can look in which folder.

I have indubitably done so with the windows pc, since all users have their folders, and the admins can see all folders, as specified in my project. The only problem is that i can't get access to the ubuntu server on the ubuntu desktop.

i've tried basically everything i could think of. not sure how to get on.

[image of ubuntu server making an user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3w6H.png)

and yet, when i restart the nmbd and smbd, restart the client, i can't access the server to see the folders, all i get is:

[image of ubuntu desktop error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKyyx.png)

so far i haven't been able to find someone with a solution to my problem, so any of you guys have an idea?

also forgot to include this, for those who wanted to see it, but i have set up the /etc/samba/smb.conf and for some of the users, it is basically this:

[picture of samba conf file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WD3OS.png)

Comment: Try gs connect or kde connect

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, i've found out that apparently when you have ubuntu 20.04 you can't just set up samba and ssh and just connect to your samba shares, but you need to implement a single line of code which is:

just below the `workgroup = WORKGROUP` tag, you have to write the code, `server min protocol = NT1`

after that, you have to restart the service with: `sudo service smbd restart`

Now i can access the folder, but i have yet to see my folders, but that is next step.

Good luck everyone

Comment: didnt work for me

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me, had 2 computers with Ubuntu 22.04, one can see the list of shares from my samba server, the other doesn't.

The samba server has both lines configured:

```bash
workgroup = WORKGROUP 
server min protocol = NT1
```

The difference is that one machine is a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04, the other machine has been updated from 18.04, and for some reason to have nautilus also needs to install gvfs*